# Given that $f(x)+f(y) = f[x \times \sqrt{1-y^2}+ y\times \sqrt{1-x^2}]$ To prove $f(4x^3-3x) + 3f(x) = 0$

Tags: functional-equations

Clearly $\arcsin x$ is one such function but how do we prove it in general?

I differentiated both sides wrt x but that didn't give me something to get even close to what's required

Comment: first try to find $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: This is obviously a typo, it should be $$f(4x^3-3x) + 3f(x) = 0.$$

Comment: Sorry for the typo . I've corrected the question

Comment: You cannont differentiate both sides if you do not even know if $f$ is continuous

Comment: $\arcsin (x)$ is **not** a solution of your FE: it is easy to get that $f(1) = 0$, but $\arcsin (1) \neq 0$.

Comment: arcsin holds true for a restricted domain

Comment: Funny you should use the word "domain" now, when you didn't include any such details in your question, neither for the function itself, nor for validity of either of the two equations. And even after it was pointed out how significant that information is, it is still missing.

Comment: Once again, as I said you, you should validate good answers for questions that have been asked more than say 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming functional equation must hold for every $x,y \in [-1, 1]$:

Set $x = y = 0$ to get $f(0) = 0$.

Set $y = 1$ to get $f(x) + f(1) = f(\sqrt{1-x^2})$, then apply the same with $-x$ instead of $x$ and compare: $f(x) + f(1) = f(-x) + f(1)$, hence $f(x)= f(-x)$.

Set $y = -x$ to get $f(x) + f(-x) = f(0) = 0$; combined with the above, $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

The desired result is now trivially true.

Answer (score 2):

The functional equation makes sense only for $x,y\in[-1,1]$.
We rewrite the functional equation as 
$$\tag0 f(\sin t)+f(\sin u)=f(\sin(t+u))\qquad\text{for }-\frac\pi2\le t,u\le\frac\pi 2 $$
(the range restriction comes from the need to have $\sqrt{1-\sin^2}=\cos$). In other words, with $g=f\circ \sin\colon[-\pi,\pi]\to \Bbb R$, we have
$$\tag1 g(x)+g(y)=g(x+y)\qquad \text{for} -\frac\pi2\le x,y\le\frac\pi 2.$$

**Preliminary remarks:**
At least without the restriction on the domain, this is a well-known problem, but even with that constraint, we find:
$$ g(0)=0$$
(and so $f(0)=0$) by setting $x=y=0$; then
$$ \tag2g(-x)=-g(x)\qquad \text{for }|x|\le \frac\pi 2,$$
(and so $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for $x\in[-1,1] $). Next, by induction
$$ g(nx)=ng(x)\qquad\text{if }n\in\Bbb N, |(n-1)x|\le\frac\pi2.$$
Using this and $(2)$,
$$ \tag3g(ax)=ag(x)\qquad \text{if }a\in\Bbb Q, |x|\le\pi, |ax|\le\pi.$$

If we make the **additional assumption** that $g$ is continuous, this implies
$$ g(x)=x\cdot g(1)\qquad \text{for }|x|\le \pi$$
and consequently,
$$ f(x)=g(\arcsin x)=g(1)\cdot \arcsin x.$$

**However,** we cannot (and need not) assume that $g$ (or $f$) is continuous.
Nevertheless, $(3)$ and $(2)$ still give us
$$\begin{align}
-f(4\sin^3t-3\sin t)&=-f(-\sin 3t)\\
&=f(\sin 3t)\\
&=g(3t)\\
&=3g(t)\\
&=3f(\sin t)
\end{align} $$
provided $|t|\le \frac \pi 3$, hence
$$ \fbox{ $f(4x^3-3x)+3f(x)=0\qquad \text{if }|x|\le\frac{\sqrt 3}2.$ }$$
So we still ought to show the result for $\frac{\sqrt 3}2<|x|<1$, i.e., for $\frac \pi3<|t|\le \frac \pi2$.
Since $f$ is odd, we need only consider $\frac\pi3<t\le\frac \pi2$ and write $t=\frac\pi3+u$ with $0<u<\frac\pi 6$.
Now we get
$$\begin{align}
-f(4\sin^3t-3\sin t)&=-f(-\sin 3t)\\
&=-f(\sin 3u)\\
&=-g(3u)\\
&=-3g(u)\\
&=-3f(\sin u)
\end{align} $$
but unfortunately, we will in general not have $f(\sin u)=-f(\sin t)$.

Comment: For any $t \in [0, \pi/2]$, we have $2g(t) = g(2t) = g(\pi-2t) = g(2(\pi/2 - t)) = 2g(\pi/2-t) = 2g(\pi/2) - 2g(t)$, hence $g(t) = {\rm const} = g(0) = 0$ for all $t \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.